# Change the numbering so that it follows the numbering of the containing section

Tags: numbering

I use the following code to mark the end of definitions but I can't see how to adapt it so that the numbering follows the section numberring.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\author{}

\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}



\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi/}{Definition}

\newenvironment{defi}
{\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}%
    %\numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \pushQED{\qed}\begin{defi/}}
    {\popQED\end{defi/}}
%
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin*{definition}{section}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection Examples}
I am a subsection
\begin{defi}
    A definition
\end{defi}

\subsubsection{Sub Subsection Example}
I am a sub subsection



\end{document}
```

As you can see there is a problem with the numbering in Definition 1.
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As always on the site please post full minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. For sniplets like this we have to guess which packages you are using (I'm guessing you are at least using `amsthm`). Additionally please change the title of the question to be more relevant. It should state that you are looking at numbering theorems.

Comment: BTW: `\newtheorem` has 3 versions, you probably need `\newtheorem{defi/}{Definition}[section]`. This is well documented in section 3 of the `amsthm` manual.

Comment: Dear @daleif, please find in my edit a minimal testable example. Thank you

Comment: Others cannot test that as is, there is no document class

Comment: The document class was present but it didn't show. I added few lines above so that it shows

Comment: Did my second comment solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much. Would you mind writing an answer so that I close this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\newtheorem` command has three different modes. See the `amsthm` manual section 3 for an explanation.

Here

```
\newtheorem{...}{...}[section]
```

Will be enough